# Reflections lib for Java: find all classes in a package

Tags: java, reflection

Further to the question posted here: [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection) I started using the Reflections library to find all classes that subclass a given type. The source code looks like this, from an answer to the linked SO question:

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */), new ResourcesScanner())
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("org.somepackage"))
    .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("org.somepackage"))));

ref.getSubtypesOf(Object.class);
```

However, after using this code obliviously for a while, I've just discovered that it will only find classes that subclass another type within this package. It won't find classes that subclass externally defined classes, say from another user-defined package.

I'm not sure how to get around this using the Reflections library. I want all classes that declare their package as 'org.somepackage', regardless of what their supertype is. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a library called [Rebound](https://bitbucket.org/gigadot/rebound/wiki/Home) (as opposed to Reflections) which searches for the subclasses of a given type and package prefix. If you set the prefix empty, it will search every class under the classpath, e.g.

```
import gigadot.exp.reflects.core.Processor;

Rebound r = new Rebound("");
Set<Class<? extends Processor>> classes = r.getSubClassesOf(Processor.class);
```

But you should be careful, because searching everything in the classpath is a slow process.

The library is much simpler than Reflections and might not do what you want. I wrote this due to my frustration when I submitted my bug report but no one there tries to solve the problem.

Comment: This looks very promising. I don't need to perform many of these calls, but it's crucial that they're completely exhaustive. Thanks a bundle, I'll look into this.

Comment: EDIT - Are Rebound's dependencies listed anywhere, e.g. log4j?

Comment: Right, got this working - works exactly as needed. Thanks for doing this, you really saved the day. I can go home now!

Comment: No problem. You could send a bug report on that site. i will try to solve it as best as i can.

Comment: You sir deserve my respect.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is, that

```
ref.getSubtypesOf(Object.class);
```

only returns the direct subclasses of Object. If you want to get all the classes from a scanned package, you should do the following:

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner(), new TypeElementsScanner())
...
Set<String> typeSet = reflections.getStore().getStoreMap().get("TypeElementsScanner").keySet();
HashSet<Class<? extends Object>> classes = Sets.newHashSet(ReflectionUtils.forNames(typeSet, reflections
            .getConfiguration().getClassLoaders()));
```

This may look a little hackish but it's the only way I found so far.
Here's a little explanation of what this does:
When Reflections is done with the scanning, it puts all the elements in a multi-value map. In the code example that I pasted, the results are put inside a map with the following keys:

```
SubTypesScanner, ResourcesScanner, TypeElementsScanner
```

The ResourceScanner excludes all files ending with .class. 
The TypeElementsScanner is a map with a key holding the name of a class, and a value of the fields etc. So if you want to get only the class names, you basically get the key set and later on, convert it to a set if classes.
The SubTypesScanner is also a map, with a key of all the super classes (including Object and interfaces) and values - the classes implementing/extending those interfaces/classes.

You can also use the SubTypesScanner if you wish, by iterating the keyset and getting all the values, but if a certain class implements an interface, you will have to deal with duplicate entities (as every class extends Object).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't know why nobody tried/gave feedback on this approach, it worked nicely for me. Thanks!

Comment: The `HashSet<Class<? extends Object>> classes` is empty(not sure why), but `Set<String> typeSet` contains the right class names.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this code works fine to load the classes of an external API, but not sure why it does not work for a built-in package like 'java.util'.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */), new ResourcesScanner())
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[2])))
                .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("org.reflections"))));
```